# git keep files from history others removed

Tags: git

I follow this http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/

but still some file hard to remove, I just need keep `/lib/request.js` `/lib/response.js` in  git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git, others should all remove.

In that article, I need tell which file to remove, e.g. the Rakefile

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' --prune-empty -- --all`

but what I want is tell which file to keep.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you shouldn't be creating an entirely new repository and just starting with those two files copied in?

```
$ mkdir my_repo
$ cd my_repo/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/annelicuss/my_repo/.git/
$ wget https://raw.github.com/visionmedia/express/master/lib/request.js
--2012-05-13 20:38:08--  https://raw.github.com/visionmedia/express/master/lib/request.js
Resolving raw.github.com... 207.97.227.243
Connecting to raw.github.com|207.97.227.243|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8878 (8.7K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `request.js'

100%[======================================>] 8,878       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2012-05-13 20:38:10 (242 MB/s) - `request.js' saved [8878/8878]

$ wget https://raw.github.com/visionmedia/express/master/lib/response.js
--2012-05-13 20:38:16--  https://raw.github.com/visionmedia/express/master/lib/response.js
Resolving raw.github.com... 207.97.227.243
Connecting to raw.github.com|207.97.227.243|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 15276 (15K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `response.js'

100%[=======================================================================================================>] 15,276      --.-K/s   in 0s      

2012-05-13 20:38:17 (280 MB/s) - `response.js' saved [15276/15276]

$ ls
request.js  response.js
$ git add *
$ git commit -m 'Add request, response from Express.'
[master (root-commit) be4a6d9] Add request, response from Express.
 2 files changed, 1059 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 request.js
 create mode 100644 response.js
$ git log
commit be4a6d9c82cb48b61f662e1e83a9f696a6685883
Author: Arlen Cuss <a@unnali.com>
Date:   Sun May 13 20:38:37 2012 +1000

    Add request, response from Express.
$
```

Please note that even this probably won't do what you want; both `request.js` and `response.js` depend on, e.g. `util.js` found in the same directory.  You may want to just add Express as a dependency of your project.

Comment: https://github.com/kissjs/kick.js/blob/master/lib/request.js I need import this file as part of my framework but I want to keep the history for respect for those contributors, what I have done is very stupid.

Comment: @guilin桂林: I don't think trying to preserve the change history will really do anything to show respect, it'll just make your job a lot harder!